# Hierarchical Databinding not working wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, telerik, radgridview

I have this code which basically places a gridview below a cell of a gridview - a hierarchical type display.

However the child grid view cannot see the data context.

I have searched and have tried many cases and it just will not work. My program is now complaining about deadlock occurring during the binding process and crashes... I am at a lost of how to get the data binding to be seen by my child grid...

```
<telerik:RadGridView Height="633" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,0,0,0" Name="radGridView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1546" Grid.Row="1" ShowGroupPanel="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}" BorderBrush="#FFD7D2D2" FontFamily="Mangal" FontSize="14" Loaded="radGridView2_Loaded" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource rowStyleSelector}" GroupRenderMode="Flat" ShowColumnSortIndexes="True" CanUserFreezeColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SetToPending}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding CollectionId}" ToolTip="{Binding Notes}"  />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding CollectionDate, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsAdvancedPayment}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LocationId}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LocationName}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding NumMachines}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding NumCollections}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Gross}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding OperatorCommission}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Actual}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding OverShort}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Advance}" ToolTip="{Binding AdvanceId}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TotalActualIn}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TotalActualOut}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Gross}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LocationCommission}" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Notes}" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}" Name="childGrid" ShowGroupPanel="False">
                </telerik:RadGridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: The error said something about a deadlock had occurred and errors like these flooded my ouptut window: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OperatorCommission' property not found on 'object' ''CollectionsModel' (HashCode=56119104)'. BindingExpression:Path=OperatorCommission; DataItem='CollectionsModel' (HashCode=56119104); target element is 'ValueSetter' (Name=''); target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Where are you setting your DataContext?

Comment: to be more specific - the error is: `ContextSwitchDeadlock` : The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x666e20 to COM context 0x666f90 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. ` - It only occurs when it try to bind `DataContext.Collections` or `DataContext.*` to my `ItemsSource`

Comment: I am setting the data context in the constructor of the control i.e. `DataContext = viewModel` where `viewModel` is  an argument to the constructor

Comment: So the `RowDetailsTemplate` is another `RadGridView` that is bound to the `Datacontext` of the Parent `RadGridView`, is that not going Stackoverflow? as the child `RadGridViews` `RowDetailsTemplate` will set more `RadGridViews` and on.. and on..

Comment: yea apparently it was but before it did that there `ContextSwitchDeadlock` occurred.

Comment: ive basically found a solution - the `DataContext` of the childgrid is whatever is bound to the parent grid...so that collection that is bound to the parent grid is the one the only the child grid sees...so I just added it to collection of my data context objects...but im curious to find out how to make the entire `DataContext` visible to the childgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive basically found a solution - the DataContext of the child grid is whatever is bound to the parent grid...so that collection that is bound to the parent grid is the one the only the child grid sees...so I just added it to collection of my data context objects...but im curious to find out how to make the entire DataContext visible to the childgrid